# How to know the structure of XUL elements hidden under moz-binding?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

(By the way, what is called the biggest Polish and English online help developers add-ons?)

I want to know the detailed structure elements: tabbrowser-tabs, arrowscrollbox, .tabs-newtab-button. I want to see what they have arguments, in particular class. In the file chrome :/ / browser / content / tabbrowser.xml not everything is either not quite clearly visible. I do not know enough to moz-binging.

I need it (among other things) to:

1 Such a style:

```
#tabbrowser-tabs > arrowscrollbox > * {
    padding: 0 !important; /* gruby HAK na odstepy z prawej i lewej */
}
```

He can remove paddingi the left and right side of scrollable tab bar. I want to know exactly which element has the paddingi, so it does not use a general selector.

2 Such a style:

```
/* przyciski przewijania paska kart */

.tabbrowser-arrowscrollbox > .scrollbutton-up,
.tabbrowser-arrowscrollbox > .scrollbutton-down {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 1px !important;
    list-style-image: none !important;
}

.scrollbutton-up {
    box-shadow:  4px 4px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38) !important;
}

.scrollbutton-down {    
    box-shadow:  4px -4px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38) !important;
}

.scrollbutton-up[disabled="true"], .scrollbutton-down[disabled="true"] {
         /* gdy niepotrzebny Cien */
  opacity: .0 !important;       
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Makes the scroll arrows are invisible, but their shadows appear, if there are any cards out of sight of the tab bar. The problem I have with that when open the card so that it appears out of view of the tab bar (eg by opening multiple links with one hand until it runs out of space on the screen for the card) is a scroll button to the tab bar illuminates in blue, indicating that the card actually opened. However, this style hides the button and leaves a shadow.

I would like to add a style for the button. Scrollbutton-down, which changes the color of the shadow of my style in blue, at the same time when the colors on the color.

3 The rest of the style tab bar:

```
#TabsToolbar:not([collapsed="true"]) + #nav-bar {
    margin-top: 0 !important; /* hak 1px - anty - wpuszczeniu paska kart na 1px pod pasek narzedzi */
}

#TabsToolbar {
    height: 26px !important;
}

#tabbrowser-tabs {
    min-height: 26px !important;
}

/* kolor paska kart */

#TabsToolbar {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .0), rgba(0, 0, 0, .04)),
        -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(220, 224, 234, 1), rgba(220, 224, 234, 1)) !important;
    /* #2b83de #E5E5E5 rgba(200, 207, 224, 1) */
}

/* karty */

.tab-background-start,
.tab-background-end,
.tab-close-button,
#alltabs-button {
    display: none !important;
}

/*.tabbrowser-tab,
.tab-stack,*/
.tab-background,
.tab-background-middle,
.tabs-newtab-button {
    background: none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}

.tabbrowser-tab:before { /* ukrywa kreski rozdzielajace */
    display: none !important;
}


.tabbrowser-tab {
    margin-bottom: 1px !important; /* to celowy efekt, ma być taki 1px odstęp podkreślający aktywną kartę */
}

.tab-content {
    padding-left: 6px !important;
    padding-right: 6px !important; /* tak naprawde to 10*/
}

/* kolory kart */

.tabbrowser-tab, .tabs-newtab-button {
         /* zwykÃÂÃÂa i nowa Karta */
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) !important;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), transparent),
        linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)) !important;

    background-position: -moz-calc(100% - 1px) -1px, 100% -1px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: 1px 100%, 1px 100%, 1px 100%, 1px 100%, 100% 100% !important;
}

tab.tabbrowser-tab[selected=true] {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 3px rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.16) !important;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)),
        linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .0), rgba(0, 0, 0, .04)),
        linear-gradient(rgba(240, 237, 244, 1), rgba(220, 227, 244, 1)) !important;
}


#tabbrowser-tabs tab.tabbrowser-tab:not([selected=true]):first-child {
         /* pierwsza zwykÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂ Karta */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), transparent),
        linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
        linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), transparent),
        linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0))!important;

    background-position: -moz-calc(100% - 1px),
        100%,
        -moz-calc(0px),
        1px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: 1px 100%, 1px 100%, 1px 100%, 1px 100% !important;
}
#tabbrowser-tabs tab.tabbrowser-tab:not([selected=true]):last-child {
         /* ostatnia zwykÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂa Karta */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), transparent),
        linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)) !important;

    background-position: 100%,
        calc(100% - 1px) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: 1px 100%, 1px 100% !important;
}
```

Overall, it simplifies the style tab bar. However, the new card (if there is not enough open tabs). Tabs-newtab-button is too wide as this style, you probably are paddingi the left and right side. In normal cards, these paddingi removes something. Tab-background-*, and probably newtab has otherwise named. 3.a When the number of cards is close to the border after which there is a different version of the new card button (without the card style) it jumps from one style to another indefinitely. This is done at the time when 2 cards are pinned, although it can also affect the resolution because when I reduced the Firefox window, it's nothing I did not notice, which does not exclude that it could happen.

4 By the way:

```
.tab-content {
    padding-left: 6px !important;
    padding-right: 6px !important; /* tak naprawde to 10*/
}
```

This style had to do 6px padding on the right side of the text, however, is set to 10px. No changes pixel by pixel, maybe it is something else calculated, script or something?

With 1,2 and 3, I would have advised, just do not know how to get it this structure.

For example, element tab.tabbrowser-tab has THEMSELVES are other elements that are adding the -moz-binding: url('chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml#tabbrowser-tab'):

```
<content context="tabContextMenu" closetabtext="Close Tab">

    <xul:stack class="tab-stack" flex="1">
        <xul:hbox class="tab-background" xbl:inherits="pinned,selected,titlechanged,fadein">
            <xul:hbox class="tab-background-start" xbl:inherits="pinned,selected,titlechanged">
            </xul:hbox>
            <xul:hbox class="tab-background-middle" xbl:inherits="pinned,selected,titlechanged">
            </xul:hbox>
            <xul:hbox class="tab-background-end" xbl:inherits="pinned,selected,titlechanged">
            </xul:hbox>
        </xul:hbox>
        <xul:hbox class="tab-content" xbl:inherits="pinned,selected,titlechanged" align="center">
            <xul:image class="tab-throbber" xbl:inherits="fadein,pinned,busy,progress,selected" role="presentation" layer="true">
            </xul:image>
            <xul:image class="tab-icon-image" xbl:inherits="src=image,fadein,pinned,selected" anonid="tab-icon-image" validate="never" role="presentation">
            </xul:image>
            <xul:label class="tab-text tab-label" flex="1" anonid="tab-label" xbl:inherits="value=visibleLabel,crop,accesskey,fadein,pinned,selected" role="presentation">
            </xul:label>
            <xul:toolbarbutton class="tab-close-button close-icon" anonid="close-button" xbl:inherits="fadein,pinned,selected">
            </xul:toolbarbutton>
        </xul:hbox>
    </xul:stack>

</content>
```

How to get to THOSE elements? For some reason I can not find content for tabbrowser-tabs, arrowscrollbox, .tabs-newtab-button. Please help. Give the contents of these elements or a tool where I can check the contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *explore* bindings at runtime, the best way is still the [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/).

Use the `File/Inspect Chrome Document` menu item to select e.g. a browser.xul instance.
From there, select the element you're interested in and e.g. play with the right panel (examine XBL Bindings by switching to the corresponding view, or CSS rules which include origin location, etc.).
The DOM Inspector also shows anonymous nodes, i.e. nodes generated by the XBL bindings. Anonymous nodes are displayed in red.

You may then cross reference stuff on [DXR](http://dxr.mozilla.org/) or [MXR](http://mxr.mozilla.org/), provides the stuff is core functionality and not added by another add-on.

From that information you could construct e.g. CSS selector. Most anonymous nodes (at least those originating from core bindings) have sensible `class` names. E.g. you could do something like (which I "constructed" just by looking at the screenshot below).

```
#urlbar .textbox-contextmenu {
  display: none;
}
```

[image: DOM Inspector screenshot]

As for documentation: It doesn't really get any better than MDN, which is admittedly rather lacking in many areas. Don't expect there is even documentation for particular bindings; the source code is the documentation.